# Interface and inheritance java

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Hello I need help with the next homework problem I have.

This is just a part of the problem, but I need only help with this part.

I want to make a small system that simulate Olympic games. There are three sports that I want to simulate, swimming, cycling and running. There are four types of athletes that I want to use, swimmers, cyclists, sprinters (who can compete in swimming, cycling and running respectively) and superAthletes who can compete in all three games (This is the one I have the most problems with). Each athlete should have a compete() method which will randomly generate a time between 10 to 20 seconds for running, 100 to 200 seconds for swimming and 500 to 800 seconds for cycling, this times will be used to determent the winner for the game.

My question is how to simulate this problem, what kind of classes to use, and what will their relations be. I would need a way to make a different game objects, like SwimGame that has a list of only Swim and Super Athlete.

This is my approach for now.

So I will have basic abstract class Athlete, and cycler, runner swimmer and superAthlete, will extend from this class.

I will also have Game abstract class, and the SwimGame, CycleGame, and RunningGame will extend from here. Every Game will have list of athlete that are competing in the game.

**How will I be able to prevent runner be added to swim game, and similar situations**

**how will I extend Calculate time, when superAthleat can participate in all the 3 games**

At first I thought that I make 3 interfaces:

```
interface swimInterface() {
    public void calculateSwimTime();
}

interface runInterface() {
    public void calculateRunTime();
}
interface cycleInterface() {
    public void calculateCycleTime();
}
```

and then make swimmerAthleate implement swimInterface, then runAthlete implement runInterface, cycleAthlete implement cycleInterface, and most importantly superAthlete implements runInterface, swimmerInterface and cycleInterface, so I would have something like this:

```
public abstract class Athlete {
    ...
    // what should be here
}

public class SwimAthlete extends Athlete implements SwimInterface {

     ...
     public void calculateSwimTime() {...}
}

public class RunAthlete extends Athlete implements RunInterface {

     ...
     public void calculateRunTime() {...}
}

public class CylcleAthlete extends Athlete implements CycleInterface {

     ...
     public void calculateCycleTime() {...}
}

public class SuperAthlete extends Athlete implements SwimInterface, CycleInterface, RunInterface() {

     public void calculateSwimTime() {...}
     public void calculateRunTime() {...}   
     public void calculateCycleTime() {...}
```

}

But then I have lot of other problems: 
If I have something like this:

```
public class Game {
    ArrayList<Athlete> listOfCompetitors;
    public Game(){
        listOfCompetitors = new ArrayList<Athlete>();
    }
}

public class SwimGame extends Game {
    // I could have something like this here
    // how could I add only SwimAthlete and SuperAthlete here

    // how to traverse the array of athletes and only call calculateSwimTime method.

} 

// similar for other games.
```

If you need more explanations, I am more than willing to discuss this question.

Comment: Q: Have you considered adding an "Event" class, that "Has a" game and an athelete?  And might also disallow "swimmer" athletes from participating in "Running" games?

Comment: When you call `compete()`, how do you know which event that athlete is competing in?  It would be better to have a separate interface for each event, each with its own method (`swim()`, `run()`, etc.), and then have each type of athlete implement the interfaces for whatever events that type is allowed to compete in.

Comment: Ok I used that approach, but then I have the problem, of how to call this methodes from diffrent games. I will update my question to reflect this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Sport
{
    void compete();
}

abstract class Athlete implements Sport
{
    String name;

    int time = 0;

    void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void setTime(int time)
    {
        this.time = time;
    }

    String getName() { return name; }
    int getTime() { return time; }
}

class Runner extends Athlete
{
    Runner(String name)
    {
        setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void compete()
    {
        int time = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * ((20d - 10d) + 1d));

        setTime(time);
    }
}

class Swimmer extends Athlete
{
    Swimmer(String name)
    {
        setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void compete()
    {
        int time = 100 + (int) (Math.random() * ((200d - 100d) + 1d));

        setTime(time);
    }
}

class Cyclist extends Athlete
{
    Cyclist(String name)
    {
        setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void compete()
    {
        int time = 500 + (int) (Math.random() * ((800d - 500d) + 1d));

        setTime(time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what to do with superAthlete, who can compete in all the 3 games.